# How can i use THIS with babel in nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, this, babeljs

In the past i could use:

```
var _this = this
...
exports.someFunction = function (req, res) {
    _this.create(someVar)
}
...
exports.create = (someVar) => {
//logic here
return something
}
```

But since i added BABEL to use GraphQl, ***package.json***:

```
"devDependencies": {
     "@babel/core": "^7.8.4",
     "@babel/node": "^7.8.4",
     "@babel/preset-env": "^7.8.4",
     "@babel/register": "^7.8.3"
   }
```

and the ***.babelrc*** file with:

```
{
   "presets": [
     [
       "@babel/env"
     ]
   ]
}
```

I get the error:

***uncaughtException: Cannot read property 'create' of null***

Please let me know what I am doing wrong or what I can do in ***.babelrc*** to allow the use of *this*

Thanks.

Comment: Can't you just reference `exports.create`?

Comment: :O its works 100%. Can you explain me why?, what have babel that change this?

Comment: Is your code really `exports.create(someVar){`, or is it something like `exports.create = (someVar) => {`?

Comment: The second way exactly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you want to reference a function which is a property of `exports`, why not reference `exports` to get to it? No need to depend on the calling context of the module:

```
exports.someFunction = function (req, res) {
    exports.create(someVar);
}
```

It sounds like a Babel module's top level is not called with a calling context, so `this` is `undefined` (just like it would be in strict mode).